# Keeping Docker container alive running Java application

Tags: docker, containers

Im having a recurring issue while trying to set up a Docker container so that it stays running.

Here is a sample of the Dockerfile that I am wanting to use:

```
RUN wget -O /usr/local/nexus-2.11.3-01-bundle.tar.gz http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-2.11.3-01-bundle.tar.gz
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN tar xvzf /usr/local/nexus-2.11.3-01-bundle.tar.gz
RUN ln -s nexus-2.11.3-01 nexus

ENV NEXUS_HOME /usr/local/nexus
ENV RUN_AS_USER root
CMD ["/usr/local/nexus/bin/nexus", "start"]

EXPOSE 8081
```

Basically when I build this, and then run it, the container just dies, and doing a docker ps command returns that there are no running containers.

As far as I know, (please correct me if I'm wrong...) the docker container should stay running so long as theres a process with a pid of 1.  Would the usage of the previous commands use PID 1, and if so, how can I force the nexus start command to use it?  Or to just keep the container alive...

The contents of a docker logs nexus gives:

```
****************************************
WARNING - NOT RECOMMENDED TO RUN AS ROOT
****************************************
Starting Nexus OSS...
Started Nexus OSS.
```

It seems to suggest that Nexus has started, but then again when I do a docker ps, I don't see it running.

Comment: What does a "logs" command show? I don't believe the PID matters at all -- only that your ENTRYPOINT/CMD is a process that doesn't terminate. I'm guessing the nexus process is dying but "logs" should give you some insight.

Comment: Hi @CashIsClay I've updated the above post with the contents of the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process running with PID 1 exits, then the container is automatically stopped. You can check on the `sonatype/nexus` repository [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sonatype/nexus/dockerfile/), using the concept of Launcher.

Here is how they are avoiding the container to exit:

```
...
RUN mkdir -p /opt/sonatype/nexus \
  && curl --fail --silent --location --retry 3 \
    https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/professional-bundle/nexus-professional-${NEXUS_VERSION}-bundle.tar.gz \
  | gunzip \
  | tar x -C /tmp nexus-professional-${NEXUS_VERSION} \
  && mv /tmp/nexus-professional-${NEXUS_VERSION}/* /opt/sonatype/nexus/ \
  && rm -rf /tmp/nexus-professional-${NEXUS_VERSION}
RUN useradd -r -u 200 -m -c "nexus role account" -d ${SONATYPE_WORK} -s /bin/false nexus
...
EXPOSE 8081
WORKDIR /opt/sonatype/nexus
USER nexus
ENV CONTEXT_PATH /
ENV MAX_HEAP 768m
ENV MIN_HEAP 256m
ENV JAVA_OPTS -server -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
ENV LAUNCHER_CONF ./conf/jetty.xml ./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml
CMD java \
  -Dnexus-work=${SONATYPE_WORK} -Dnexus-webapp-context-path=${CONTEXT_PATH} \
  -Xms${MIN_HEAP} -Xmx${MAX_HEAP} \
  -cp 'conf/:lib/*' \
  ${JAVA_OPTS} \
  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.Launcher ${LAUNCHER_CONF}
```

Since it is an open repository, you can directly refer to their repo, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess from the logs is that running `/usr/local/nexus/bin/nexus start` would start it as a daemon.

That would cause another process to spawn and the one that started the daemon would exit, terminating the container.

One solution is to start the process not as a daemon, but I couldn't find a option to do this in your nexus case.

Another is to use something like supervisord as the CMD to docker. Then make it start your process.